# Как определить число различных элементов в упорядоченном списке?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Подкиньте идею или код(в котором я буду разбираться)/
Думаю сделать это через два цикла for. Если есть более короткое решение, напишите мне.

Задача:

> Дан список, упорядоченный по неубыванию элементов в нем. Определите, сколько в нем различных элементов.

Comment: Можно через сортировку, можно через set, можно и вправду двойным циклом: добавляем i-тый элемент в массив ans, если в массиве a[i] not in ans. А, если упорядоченный, то просто проверить, что данный элемент не равен предыдущему

Comment: список упорядоченный, а значит, вы можете за 1 проход подсчитать дубликаты. Зная количество дубликатов уже просто найти количество различных значений.

Answer (score 4):

Хватит и одного цикла:  считать разницу двух соседних элементов. Если не 0, то они различные. Это если числа. Если не числа, то просто сравнивать соседние элементы.

Но вообще

```
n = len(set(spisok))
```

Comment: Всё-таки если в условии подсвечено, что дан отсортированный список, то вряд ли ожидается, что это надо решать через set.

Comment: @Xander я потому и написал целый первый абзац

Comment: @Xander про сет тем не менее ограничений тоже нет

Answer (score 3):

А вот ещё такой забавный вариант у меня получился чисто по приколу:

```
print(sum(x != y for x,y in zip(a, a[1:])) + bool(a))
```

Второе слагаемое нужно, чтобы правильно учесть как пустой список, так и первый элемент списка если список не пустой. А первое слагаемое считает, сколько было изменений значения в списке после первого элемента.

Answer (score 2):

самый быстрый способ (раз упорядоченный список):

```
nums = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]

count = 1
for i in range(1, len(nums)):
    if nums[i - 1] != nums[i]:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

или чуть сократив код:

```
count = 1
for i in range(1, len(nums)):
    count += nums[i - 1] != nums[i]
```

правда стоит сделать проверку для ситуации, когда список пустой

из той же серии (если требуется не только подсчитать кол-во элементов, но и найти эти элементы)

```
count = len([nums[0]] + [nums[i] for i in range(1, len(nums)) if nums[i - 1] != nums[i]])
```

Это все требует одного прохода по списку

Можно написать очень короткий код, но по времени работы для такой задачи он будет неоптимальным

```
count = len(set(nums))
```

Самый неоптимальный по времени работы код

```
nums = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]

res = []
for elem in nums:
    if elem not in res:
        res.append(elem)

print(len(res))
```

Comment: а `count` не должен быть равен `0` в начале ?

Comment: С пустым списком неправильно будет работать. Впрочем, пустой список видимо не ожидается.

Comment: @n1tr0xs, нет ибо мы первый элемент сразу берем

Comment: @CrazyElf,поэтому я и написал что нужна на этопроверка